# Simple Probability Question: Deck of Cards

Tags: probability

Three cards are randomly drawn from a deck of $52$ playing cards. What is the probability that all three cards will be of the same suit and will all have face value between 2 and 10.

My Solution: $\dfrac{9}{52} \cdot \dfrac{8}{51} \cdot \dfrac{7}{50} = 0.4\%$ but not sure

Comment: That's not what I get.

Comment: Remember, the *suit* of the *first* card can be anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly we fix sample space $$\Omega=\{A \subset \{1,2,..,52\}: |A|=3\} \implies |\Omega|={{52}\choose{3}}$$

Now we have 4 possibilities to fix suit, once fixed it we have (9C3) possibilities to choose three card from 2 to 10.

So the probability is $$\frac{4*{{9}\choose{3}}}{{{52}\choose{3}}} \sim0.015$$

Comment: @N.F.Taussig I edited it, thanks